# delete where not in also deletes all newly inserted rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a feature in which I mark/unmark all from the frontend, and `INSERT IGNORE` if atlready exists in the table, and after the insert query finishes, it deletes all records that do not exists in the php array.

I'm having trouble with the delete query, It seems to delete all the newly inserted rows.

Note: that I have set (placeId, methodId, isCountry) as unique

Here is my query for the delete:

```
DELETE FROM placeMethods
WHERE (placeId, methodId, isCountry) NOT IN 
(('4','11', '0'), ('5','11', '0')) AND methodId IN ('11', '12')
```

and here's how I did it in php,
I have an associative array like this (basically, these are all the marked places from method 11, all the rest including all places from method 12 are unmarked):

```
[
    ['placeId' => 4, 'methodId' => 11], 
    ['placeId' => 5, 'methodId' => 11]
]
```

and inside the function is:

```
$mappings = [];
$placeIds = array_column($placesMethods, 'placeId');
$methodIds = array_column($placesMethods, 'methodId');

foreach ($placeIds as $index => $mappings[]) {
    $mappings[] = $methodIds[$index];
}
$uniqueMethodIds = array_unique($methodIds);

$placesPlaceholder = implode(",", array_fill(0, count($placeIds), "(?,?,0)"));

$temp = implode("','", $uniqueMethodIds);

$insert = "
            INSERT IGNORE INTO placeMethods
            (placeId, methodId, isCountry)
            VALUES
            $placesPlaceholder 
        ";
$insrtStmt = $this->pdo->prepare($insert);
 
if ($insrtStmt->execute($mappings)) {
    $delete = "
                DELETE FROM placeMethods
                WHERE
                (placeId, methodId, isCountry) NOT IN 
                ($placesPlaceholder) AND
                methodId IN ('$temp')
            ";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($delete);
    $stmt->execute($mappings);

}
```

However, the last delete query seems to delete all the newly inserted files even though I have set the values in `IN` and `NOT IN` clauses

Comment: Why aren't you using placeholders for `methodId IN (...)`, like you do for `$placesPlaceholder`?

Comment: Ahhh yes, another typo.
Also, I've tried using placeholder for methodId and it still the same

Comment: It works as expected when you do the queries by hand, but fails when you do it from PDO?

Comment: Edit - It seems you fixed the typos |  I'm having trouble understanding your methodology on this, Why not just DELETE and use case parameters for your query with your methodid?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, not sure if it's really the query itself or just how I built the query in php.

Comment: @Byte can you provide some example? thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're building the query correctly. But I suggest you do `var_dump($delete, $mappings);` to make sure they both contain what you expect. Your way of building `$mappings` is confusing, I suggest simplifying it.

Comment: it seems that in my code, instead of `(countryId, methodId, isCountry)`, I accidentally put `(countryId, methodId, countryId)`, now, the problem is that, it's not deleting anything that does not exists in the array.

Comment: Maybe everything that doesn't exist in the array has a different methodId, so `AND methodId IN ($temp)` is preventing them from being deleted.

Comment: I see, what happens is that if it can't find any records in the table which does not exist in the array, then it's normal that it is not deleting anything.